# When is a call to "synchronize()" not necessary in C++ AMP?

Tags: c++, c++-amp

Background: For a C++ AMP overview, see Daniel Moth's [recent BUILD talk](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Give-A-Session-On-C-AMP-Here-Is-How.aspx).

Going through the initial walk-throughs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Hello-World-In-C-AMP.aspx), [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Matrix-Multiplication-With-C-AMP.aspx), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/21/10214538.aspx).

Only in that last reference do they make a call to `array_view.synchronize()`.

In these simple examples, is a call to `synchronize()` not needed? When is it safe to exclude? Can we trust parallel_for_each to behave "synchronously" without it (w/r/t the proceeding code)?

Comment: By the way what do I need to try c++ AMP; I am using VS 2010?

Comment: now I get "runtime_exception: Failed to create a buffer". Stack trace shows "vcamp110d.dll!Concurrency::details::_Buffer::_Create_buffer(..."

Comment: C++ AMP is not supported in VS 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use synchronize() when you want to access the data **without** going through the array_view interface. If all of your access to the data uses array_view operators and functions, you don't need to use synchronize(). As Daniel mentioned, the destructor of an array_view forces a synchronize as well, and it's better to call synchronize() in that case so you can get any exceptions that might be thrown.

The synchronize function *forces* an update to the buffer within the calling context -- that is if you write data on the GPU and then call synchronize in CPU code, at that point the updated values are copied to CPU memory.

This seems obvious from the name, but I mention it because other array_view operations can cause a 'synchronize' as well. C++ AMP array_view tries it best to make copying between the CPU and GPU memory implict -- any operation which reads data through the array view interface will cause a copy as well.

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
array_view<int, 1> av(10, v);
parallel_for_each(av.grid, [=](index<1> i) restrict(direct3d) {
   av[i] = 7;
}
// at this point, data isn't copied back
std::wcout << v[0]; // should print 0

// using the array_view to access data will force a copy
std::wcout << av[0]; // should print 7

// at this point data is copied back
std::wcout << v[0]; // should print 7
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Next question I'd have would be regarding concurrency - if two "parallel_for_each" operations are dispatched sequentially in code, can we rely on the first computation completing before the second begins? Perhaps this is a good topic for a new post - I'll try to get some more experience with the API to formulate a good question or two.

Answer (score 4):

my_array_view_instance.synchronize is not required for the simple examples I showed because the destructor calls synchronize. Having said that, I am not following best practice (sorry), which is to explicitly call synchronize. The reason is that if any exceptions are thrown at that point, you would not observe them if you left them up to the destructor, so please call synchronize explicitly.

Cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed the second question in your post about parallel_for_each being synchronous vs asyncrhonous (sorry, I am used to 1 question per thread ;-)
"Can we trust parallel_for_each to behave "synchronously" without it (w/r/t the proceeding code)?"

The answer to that is on my post about parallel_for_each:
http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/parallelforeach-From-Amph-Part-1.aspx

..and also in the BUILD recording you pointed to from 29:20-33:00
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-802T

In a nutshell, no you cannot trust it to be synchronous, it is asyncrhonous. The (implicit or explicit) synchronization point is any code that tries to access the data that is expected to be copied back from the GPU as a result of your parallel loop.

Cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that it's never safe to exclude because in a multi-threaded (concurrent or parallel) it's never safe to assume anything. There are certain guarantees which certain constructs give you but, you have to super careful and meticulous not to break these guarantees by introducing something which you think is fine to do but when in reality there's a lot of complexity underpinning the whole thing.

Haven't spent any time with C++-AMP yet but I'm inclined to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts (and for the new C++-AMP tag).

Comment: Another way to show appricatation for answers is to vote on them ;)